# Как правильно доработать скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, доработать скрипт. Блок `.panel` появляется тогда, когда блок `.content` при прокрутке страницы достигает верхнего края экрана - это правильно, так и нужно. А как же сделать, чтобы этот же блок `.panel` еще и прятался когда при прокрутке страницы мы видим уже нижний край блока `.content`? Благодарю!

```js
        $(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var distanceTop = $('.content').offset().top;
   if  ($(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop)
    $('.panel').animate({'left':'50px'},500);
   else
    $('.panel').stop(true).animate({'left':'-50px'},200);
  });
 });
```

```css
.header {
height: 1000px;
background: green;
}
.footer {
height: 1000px;
background: blue;
}
.content {
height: 3000px;
}
.panel {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: chocolate;
position: fixed;
top: 45%;
left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Comment: если этот блок  у вас представляет кнопку "Вверх", то на вашем месте при достижении нижнего края я бы этот блок не скрывал, а фиксировал в позиции, чтобы он просто не заезжал на футер

Comment: дак а в чем сложность то у вас возникла? вам теперь надо знать при прокрутке расстояние до верха футера, а не контента, и написать аналогичное условие, или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно помочь:

```js
$(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            var element = $('.content');
            var distanceTop = element.offset().top;
            var distanceHeight = element.offset().top - ($(window).height() - element.height())
            if (windowScroll > distanceTop && windowScroll < distanceHeight)
                $('.panel').animate({'left':'50px'},500);
            else
                $('.panel').stop(true).animate({'left':'-50px'},200);
        });
    });
```

```css
.header {
height: 1000px;
background: green;
}
.footer {
height: 1000px;
background: blue;
}
.content {
height: 3000px;
}
.panel {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background: chocolate;
position: fixed;
top: 45%;
left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
<div class="panel"></div>
```

Нужно добавить вот такую проверку:

```
element.offset().top - ($(window).height() - element.height()
```

Comment: Я ничего кроме jq не менял, должно работать.